# Install GNOME/KDE on RedHat without direct internet connection

Tags: installation, virtual-machine, redhat, gnome, kde-plasma

I need to have a virtual machine with RedHat and Oracle DB and Anaconda installed on it, for testing some python script with connection to Oracle DB.

I have a Windows 10 machine which cannot be connected to internet, I have installed Virtual Box on it and installed RedHat Enterprise Linux 7 installed on a VM. Now my VM has only command line interface and I couldn't find any guide for installation of GNOME or KDE without internet.

Is there a way of downloading the GUI packages on another (Windows) machine and installing it on the RedHat VM via USB? Or is there an existing VM image that contains all I need (RedHat with GUI and preferably Oracle DB isntalled) that I can directly get and use?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Download the installation ISO (the DVD image) and either use it to do a fresh install of the system (using Anaconda) that would include a graphical environment, or set up a local Yum repository from the ISO to install packages on an already existing installation.

For the first method (a fresh install), you just need to put the ISO on a disk that VirtualBox can see. The easiest way is to copy it over to the host machine on which VirtualBox is running. See [2.3.2. Installation Source on a Hard Drive](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/Installation_Guide/sect-making-media-additional-sources.html#sect-making-media-sources-hdd) of the RHEL Installation Guide.

For the second method (using the install ISO as an offline Yum repo), again, copy the ISO to the host machine and then mount the ISO as a disk in the VM (or copy it to the VM itself, but that's unnecessary), and follow the instructions in [8.1.4. Upgrading the System Off-line with ISO and Yum](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-US/Red_Hat_Enterprise_Linux/7/html/System_Administrators_Guide/ch-yum.html#s1-yum-upgrade-system) of the RHEL System Administrator's Guide.

To get the installation ISO, go to https://access.redhat.com/products/red-hat-enterprise-linux/.